# Web API 2 SIgnin

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have problem with login method 
, i Use Asp.Net Identity Database but i have problem when test api , it's crash at variable result and get 500 Internal Server Error
,

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return Ok();
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                //return GetErrorResult(result);
                return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                    "Check your email and password again"));
        }

    }
```

And this is error

> "$id": "1", "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage":
>   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException", "StackTrace": " at
>   Land.Controllers.API.Customer.AccountController.d__21.MoveNext()
>   in
>   F:\Me\Private\Land\Land\Controllers\API\Customer\AccountController.cs:line
>   206 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"

Comment: Do you know which line it crashed on?  Check the following things: connection string is correct, username/password in connectionstring is correct.  Not sure how far along you are, but check to make sure the user exists in the database as well.

Comment: Check if the model is null?

Comment: I check model by if(! Model.state.isvalid)  and it give me that it's correct, the problem in  var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
It crash and don't give me any result

Comment: How are you testing it? Can you share your client code?